# What is the need of $scope.closeModal?

Tags: ionic-framework

Here is my code..If I remove close modal function,there is no effect. If I click any where outside the modal, the modal closes. But I need this close modal function as I need to set a flag in it for further use. How can I proceed further?

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
$scope.openModal();
}
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl("settings/settingsModal.html", {
       scope: $scope,

       animation: 'slide-in-up'
     }).then(function(modal) {
       $scope.modal = modal;
     });
   $scope.openModal = function(){
      $scope.modal.show();
   }
   $scope.closeModal = function(){
     $scope.modal.hide();

    };
   }
```

Comment: Do you want get data from modal when the modal is closed?

Answer (score 1):

There are a two ways of implementing modal in Ionic. One way is to add separate template and the other is to add it on top of the regular HTML file, inside script tags. First thing we need to do is to connect our modal to our controller using angular dependency injection. Then we need to create modal. We will pass in scope and add animation to our modal.

After that we are creating functions for opening, closing, destroying modal and the last two functions are place where we can write code that will be triggered if modal is hidden or removed. If you don't want to trigger any functionality when modal is removed or hidden you can delete the last two functions.

**Controller's Code:**

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
  scope: $scope,
  animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
  $scope.modal = modal;
});

 $scope.openModal = function() {
  $scope.modal.show();
 };

 $scope.closeModal = function() {
  $scope.modal.hide();
 };

 //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
 $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $scope.modal.remove();
 });

 // Execute action on hide modal
 $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
  // Execute action
 });

 // Execute action on remove modal
 $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
  // Execute action
 });

 });
```

**HTML Code :**

```
   <script id = "my-modal.html" type = "text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view>
      <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class = "title">Modal Title</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

     <ion-content>
     <button class = "button icon icon-left ion-ios-close-outline"
        ng-click = "closeModal()">Close Modal</button>
     </ion-content>
    </ion-modal-view>
  </script>
```

There are also other options for modal optimization. I already showed how to use scope and animation. The table below shows other options.

[Modal options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SliMw.png)

Answer (score 0):

The close modal function is meant for situations where you would like to close the modal manually. For example after a certain time it has been open or if something happens/the user does something for example presses a button.

There are ways of listening to when the modal is hidden/removed which will suit your situation and needs. For example:

```
// Execute action on hide modal
$scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
  // Execute action
  console.log('modal was hidden');
});

// Execute action on remove modal
$scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
  // Execute action
  console.log('modal was removed');
});
```

With these you should be able to do what I understood you are wanting to do.

Straight from the documentation: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/